# How to handle multiple clients in JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I'm implementing a game in JSP and Servlets. The game should support multiple players.
It is obvious that each player ID is generated on the server side. But where do I store it on the client side, so I can retrieve it later (from within the servlet) when the client calls for the Servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are handled automatically by the servlet framework, and you retrieve the session by calling [`request.getSession()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29) in a servlet.

The session is available in different ways once you start using a framework once you outgrow servlets (this happens quickly) and is framework-dependent.

Comment: Can I keep HashMap of <clientId,HttpSession> and check which player is communicating with me? How do I test it correctly?

Comment: I don't think you really understand what the session is. If you put a client ID in the session you already *know* the client ID, because it's in the session.

Comment: Does 2 different tabs on the same browser will have different sessions?

Comment: @MichaelS Nope (it used to depend on the browser, it still might, but I doubt it). If you need to differentiate between tabs you'll have to implement some form of "conversation" scope like Seam does and keep a unique token per-request, including on links.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot I will dig into it!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how long you want the client to remember the player ID.

1. During the session: The session is a good place
2. During his subsequent visists: A (permanent) cookie is a good place

Session: `request.getSession()`

Cookie: `request.getCookies()` and `response.addCookie(cookie)`

Answer (score 0):

Session ids are usually stored in a cookie.

I'd be amazed if JSP doesn't have a session library that would take care of all that for you.